# java request.getQueryString() value different between chrome and ie browser

Tags: java, jsp, url, servlets

I have a request,In  Browser address bar enter:

```
http://localhost:8888/cmens-tops-outwear/t-b-f-a-c-s-fLoose-p-g-e-i-o.htm?'"--></style></script><script>netsparker(0x0000E1)</script>=
```

`Tomcat6.0.35` i have set `URIEncoding="UTF-8"`

Use `request.getQueryString()` in servlet:

if `chrome`,i get

```
'%22--%3E%3C/style%3E%3C/script%3E%3Cscript%3Enetsparker(0x0000E1)%3C/script%3E=
```

if `ie`,I get

```
'"--></style></script><script>netsparker(0x0000E1)</script>=
```

Why?

**Additional**

I want to get `request.getQueryString()` to create a uri

```
URI uri = URI.create(url)
```

if ie:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 36: /cmens/t-b-f-a-c-s-f-p-g-e-i-o.htm?'"--></style></script><script>netsparker(0x0000E1)</script>
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3072)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3024)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:840)
```

**How to determine the queryString whether has be encoded?**

Comment: well Chrome is just encoding the special characters that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) is per definition undecoded. See also the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29) (emphasis mine):

> #### Returns:
>
> a String containing the query string or null if the URL contains no query string. **The value is not decoded by the container.**

Basically, you need to URL-decode it yourself if you'd like to parse it manually instead of using `getParameterXxx()` methods for some reason (which implicitly decodes the parameters!).

```
String decodedQueryString = URLDecoder.decode(request.getQueryString(), "UTF-8");
```

As to why Chrome sends it encoded while IE not, that's because Chrome is doing a better job of handling HTTP requests the safe/proper way. This is beyond your control. Just always URL-decode the query string yourself if you intend to parse it manually for some reason. The `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` configuration has only effect on `getParameterXxx()` methods during GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome version is URLEncoded while the IE string is decoded.

Use this tool to compare the URLEncoded and decoded versions: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome uses the URL encoding way, but IE is using strings.

For example: " is %22 in URL encoding.

< is %3E
and > is %3C

Chrome is doing it the "right way" but IE just can't do as all the others.

You can find complete list of URL characters here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Chrome sends the url encoded. Try decoding the query string using

```
URLDecoder.decode(queryString, "UTF-8");
```

As stated by the javadoc, the query string is not decoded by the container:

> returns a String containing the query string or null if the URL contains no query string. The value is not decoded by the container.

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString%28%29)